# Sed in Ubuntu Linux, replacing a pattern by printing in a new line

Tags: vim, ubuntu, sed

Using Sed, I wanted to replace this long line:

```
http://download.lenovo.com/UserFiles/Driver/en/Downloads%20and%20Drivers/Z570/Win7/IN3ETN46WW5.exehttp://download.lenovo.com/UserFiles/Driver/en/Downloads%20and%20Drivers/Z570/Win%207%20Update/IN1AUD25WW5.exehttp://download.lenovo.com/UserFiles/Driver/en/Downloads%20and%20Drivers/Z570/Win7/IN2VDO61WW6.exehttp://download.lenovo.com/UserFiles/Driver/en/Downloads%20and%20Drivers/Z570/Win7/IN1SRM38WW5.exehttp://download.lenovo.com/UserFiles/Driver/en/Downloads%20and%20Drivers/Z570/Win7/IN2VDO63WW5.exehttp://download.lenovo.com/UserFiles/Driver/en/Downloads%20and%20Drivers/Z570/Win7/IN6WLN49WW5.exe
```

into this:

```
http://download.lenovo.com/UserFiles/Driver/en/Downloads%20and%20Drivers/Z570/Win7/IN3ETN46WW5.exe
http://download.lenovo.com/UserFiles/Driver/en/Downloads%20and%20Drivers/Z570/Win%207%20Update/IN1AUD25WW5.exe
http://download.lenovo.com/UserFiles/Driver/en/Downloads%20and%20Drivers/Z570/Win7/IN2VDO61WW6.exe
```

I tried (inside vim)

```
:%s#http://#\nhttp://#g
```

and it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to do this with `vim` or `sed` or both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason `vim` wants `\r` in the replacement, so if you change your substitution to:

```
:%s#http://#\r&#g
```

it will work.

If you don't mind the extra whitespace, this will work in `sed`:

```
sed 's#http://#\n&#g' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

If extra whitespace is annoying, you could use `GNU awk`:

```
awk -F "http" '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) print FS $i }' file.txt
```

Results:

```
http://download.lenovo.com/UserFiles/Driver/en/Downloads%20and%20Drivers/Z570/Win7/IN3ETN46WW5.exe
http://download.lenovo.com/UserFiles/Driver/en/Downloads%20and%20Drivers/Z570/Win%207%20Update/IN1AUD25WW5.exe
http://download.lenovo.com/UserFiles/Driver/en/Downloads%20and%20Drivers/Z570/Win7/IN2VDO61WW6.exe
http://download.lenovo.com/UserFiles/Driver/en/Downloads%20and%20Drivers/Z570/Win7/IN1SRM38WW5.exe
http://download.lenovo.com/UserFiles/Driver/en/Downloads%20and%20Drivers/Z570/Win7/IN2VDO63WW5.exe
http://download.lenovo.com/UserFiles/Driver/en/Downloads%20and%20Drivers/Z570/Win7/IN6WLN49WW5.exe
```